# Socket programming Issue - C

Tags: c, sockets, unix, server, client

I am trying to make a simple echo program which includes a client and a server utilizing TCP protocol under Socket Programming. For this purpose I am using C to write both server.c and client.c.

The issue I am getting is in server.c program where I am trying to reveive a message from the client, after the connection has been made but keeps on failing. This happens in the recv() API that is in the server program. Here are the two programs:

1.) Server.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>

int main(){

    //Let's create a socket here.
    int serverSoc = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);


    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo;
    serverInfo.sin_family = PF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(8000);
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    socklen_t addrLen = (socklen_t)sizeof(serverInfo);

      //We need to bind the socket to the port number. So, here we make use of the in-built struct
    if(bind(serverSoc,(struct sockaddr*)&serverInfo,addrLen)<0){
        printf("The binding of the server socket with the given port has been unsuccessful\n.");
        return -1;
    }

    //After binding the socket, here we listen for connections from the clients
    if(listen(serverSoc, 1)<0){ //We used 1 here in the int backlog because that specifies the number of pending connections that the queue will hold. This will help in the case when multiple clients try to connect to the server.
        printf("We have an error in connecting to the client(s)\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    if(accept(serverSoc,(struct sockaddr*)&serverInfo,&addrLen)<0){
        printf("We have an error accepting the connections from the client(s).\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char recvBuff[50];
    if(recv(serverSoc,&recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff),0)<0){
     printf("We have an error receiveing messages from the client.\n");
     printf("%zd\n",recv(serverSoc,recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff),0));
     return -1;
    }else{
        printf("The size of recvBuff is:%d\n",(int)sizeof(recvBuff));
        printf("%s\n",recvBuff); 
    }
     
     char sendBuff[50] = "hello";
    if(send(serverSoc,&sendBuff,sizeof(sendBuff),0)<0){
        printf("We have an error sending message to the client.\n");
        return -1;
    }else{
         printf("%zd\n",send(serverSoc,&sendBuff,sizeof(sendBuff),0));
    }

return 0;
}
```

2.) Client.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    char clientRecv[50];
    char clientSend[50] = "Hello Server\n";
    //Here, we create a socket for the client with the in-built function socket that we get from sys/socket.h, socket(int domain, int type , int protocol)
    int clientSoc = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    printf("The client socket has been assigned the value of: %d\n",clientSoc);
    if(clientSoc < 0){
        printf("We have an error");
        return (-1);
    }

    //all the struct(s) that are needed for the program
    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo;
    serverInfo.sin_family = PF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(8000);
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Connecting the client to the server
    if((connect(clientSoc,(struct sockaddr*)&serverInfo,(socklen_t)sizeof(serverInfo)))< 0){
        printf("Not connecting");
return(-1);
    }

if(send(clientSoc,&clientSend,sizeof(clientSend),0)<0){
    printf("We are having an error in sending the message.\n");
    return -1;
}
int clientRecvmsg = (int)recv(clientSoc, &clientRecv,sizeof(clientRecv),0);
if(clientRecvmsg<0){
    printf("We have error receiving messages from the server.\n");
}else{
printf("clientRecvmsg: %s\n", clientRecv);
return -1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `accept` returns the new socket you should use to communicate with the client, or -1 if `accept` was unsuccessful.

Comment: You should really use `getaddrinfo` rather than that outdated IPv4 stuff.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek, Should I set the 2nd and 3rd parameter in the accept function as NULL then?

Comment: @Cheatah, Thank you for your reply, I will study what "getaddrinfo" is and try to implement that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not call `recv()` on the listening server socket (`serverSoc`). That socket is made only to accept new connections. Communication needs to occur on the connected socket that `accept()` returns.

So, do not use this:

```c
accept(serverSoc,...);
recv(serverSoc,...);
```

but do use this:

```c
int conSoc = accept(serverSoc,...);
recv(conSoc,...);
```

Some explanation, if needed.

Note that if you accept only one connection simultaneously (which you do, currently), this may seem as an overcomplication (why would the API force me to use 2 different sockets? one may ask).

But if you don't, well, consider that two different things may happen anytime, concurrently, to the server:

- An already connected client may send or read some data. Or disconnect
- A new, not already connected client may connect.

Imagine, a web server: while it is serving some big files to, say, three different clients, you don't want the server to refuse any connection from a 4th client (at least not if you are Google. My server probably can). So, while that server is serving 3 clients (reading what they write, writing what they read), it needs 4 sockets. 3 (`conSoc`-like) to send/receive data to each of the 3 clients, and a 4th (`serverSoc`-like) to get incoming  new connections.

In C you can implement that with threads or processes. Or with `poll` or `select`. In which case you would either have 4 threads/processes (1 `recv`ing/`send`ing from/to each client, on `conSoc`-like sockets, and another `accepting` new client on `serverSoc). Or pass 4 sockets to` listen`/`poll`(3`conSoc`-like to watch when a connected client is ready to recv or send. A 1` serverSoc`to watch when a new connection is ready to be`accept``ed.)

So, well, long story short, the `serverSoc` socket that you use to received new connections is not the same as the `conSoc` you use to talk into those connections. Even if, with 1 connection at a time, it is not obvious why.

Comment: And don't forget to `close()` the `conSoc` when you are done using it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, chrslg. I will try to implement the pointers you gave.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main problems with your code:

1. your server is using the wrong socket with `recv()` and `send()`.  It needs to use the connected socket that `accept()` returns, not the listening socket that `accept()` is being called on.  That is why `recv()` is failing.
2. your client is `connect()`'ing to the wrong IP address.  `INADDR_ANY` (`0.0.0.0`) is OK for a server to listen on (it will listening on all local interfaces), but is not OK for a client to connect to.  You must connect to an actual IP address that the server is bound to and listening on.  For instance, if your client and server are running on the same PC, you can connect to `INADDR_LOOPBACK` (`127.0.0.1`) instead.

On a lesser note, your code has some other problems, too:

- you say you are trying to make an echo server, but your service is not trying to echo back what the client has sent.
- after calling `recv()`, your server is using `recvBuff` incorrectly.  It is not guaranteed to be null-terminated (even if the client sends a null-terminator), but you are assuming it always will be. You are ignoring the return value of `recv()`, which tells you how many bytes were actually written into `recvBuff`.
- there is no 1:1 relationship between sends and reads in TCP.  Either operation can report fewer bytes than requested, so you have to be prepared to handle that condition.  If `send()` reports fewer bytes than you asked to send, you have to call `send()` again to send the remaining unsent bytes. Likewise, if `recv()` reports fewer bytes than you asked to read, you have to call `recv()` again to read the remaining unread bytes.
- you are calling `recv()` and `send()` inside of your print messages, which you should not be doing at all, especially in error messages.

Try something more like this instead:

Server.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>

ssize_t sendAll(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len) {
    const char *pbuf = (const char*) buf;
    while (len > 0) {
        ssize_t numSent = send(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (numSent < 0) return -1;
        pbuf += numSent;
        len -= numSent;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    //Let's create a socket here.
    int serverSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (serverSoc < 0){
        printf("The creation of the server socket has been unsuccessful\n.");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo;
    memset(&serverInfo, 0, sizeof(serverInfo));
    serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(8000);
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    //We need to bind the socket to the port number. So, here we make use of the in-built struct
    if (bind(serverSoc, (struct sockaddr*)&serverInfo, (socklen_t)sizeof(serverInfo)) < 0){
        printf("The binding of the server socket with the given port has been unsuccessful\n.");
        return -1;
    }

    //After binding the socket, here we listen for connections from the clients
    if (listen(serverSoc, 1) < 0){ //We used 1 here in the int backlog because that specifies the number of pending connections that the queue will hold. This will help in the case when multiple clients try to connect to the server.
        printf("We have an error in listening for clients\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    int clientSoc = accept(serverSoc, NULL, NULL);
    if (clientSock < 0){
        printf("We have an error accepting the connection from a client.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char recvBuff[50];
    ssize_t numRecvd, numSent;

    while ((numRecvd = recv(clientSoc, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0)) > 0){
        printf("The size of recvBuff is: %zd\n", numRecvd);
        printf("%.*s\n", (int)numRecvd, recvBuff); 

        if (sendAll(clientSoc, recvBuff, numRecvd) < 0){
            printf("We have an error sending a message to the client.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    
    if (numRecvd < 0){
        printf("We have an error receiving a message from the client.\n");
        return -1;
    } 

    printf("The client disconnected.\n");

    close(clientSoc);
    close(serverSoc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Client.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

ssize_t sendAll(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len) {
    const char *pbuf = (const char*) buf;
    while (len > 0) {
        ssize_t numSent = send(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (numSent < 0) return -1;
        pbuf += numSent;
        len -= numSent;
    }
    return 0;
}

ssize_t recvAll(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len) {
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (len > 0) {
        ssize_t numRecvd = recv(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (numRecvd <= 0) return numRecvd;
        pbuf += numRecvd;
        len -= numRecvd;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    char clientRecv[50];
    char clientSend[50] = "Hello Server\n";

    //Here, we create a socket for the client with the in-built function socket that we get from sys/socket.h, socket(int domain, int type , int protocol)
    int clientSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    printf("The client socket has been assigned the value of: %d\n", clientSoc);
    if (clientSoc < 0){
        printf("We have an error");
        return (-1);
    }

    //all the struct(s) that are needed for the program
    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo;
    memset(&serverInfo, 0, sizeof(serverInfo));
    serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(8000);
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;

    //Connecting the client to the server
    if (connect(clientSoc, (struct sockaddr*)&serverInfo, (socklen_t)sizeof(serverInfo)) < 0){
        printf("Not connecting");
        return -1;
    }

    size_t len = strlen(clientSend);

    if (sendAll(clientSoc, clientSend, len) < 0){
        printf("We are having an error in sending the message.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ssize_t clientRecvmsg = recvAll(clientSoc, clientRecv, min(sizeof(clientRecv), len));
    if (clientRecvmsg <= 0){
        printf("We have error receiving a message from the server.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("clientRecvmsg: %.*s\n", (int)clientRecvmsg, clientRecv);

    close(clientSoc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Remy Lebeau. I just had a question, why did you use while loop in the server after the accept instead of an 'if' and also why not send a string through the send() function?

Comment: "*why did you use while loop in the server after the accept instead of an 'if'*" - because an ECHO server should echo back whatever the client sends. Also, there is no 1:1 relationship between sends and reads in TCP, so you have to be prepared to handle the case where `recv()` returns fewer bytes than requested. The loop is so the server can handle all of the data that the client sends, until the client disconnects. "*why not send a string through the send() function?*" - again, because an ECHO server should echo the client's data exactly, not send its own data.

Comment: Also, I did make the changes you referred to Remy Lebeau. The code runs completely fine.

Comment: Hello Remy, I actually ran the two codes that you wrote for server and client. I had some doubts regarding them. 1.) In the client program, line 64 which is ssize_t clientRecvmsg = recvAll() you have given 4 parameters but the function just has three. 2.) Why did you make two different functions by the name sendAll and recvAll?  3.) When I ran the code and check for the processes in terminal, it showed that client and server both had processes with different PID is that normal result for the code?

Comment: Also Remy, The code ran when I commented on this line "serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;"

Comment: @Inderjeet 1) the client is passing 3 values to `recvAll()` - the socket, the buffer, and the result of `min(sizeof(clientRecv), len)` for the buffer size. 2) as I said earlier, `send()`/`recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested, so `sendAll()`/`recvAll()` call `send()`/`recv()` in loops to ensure all requested bytes are transferred. 3) yes, both client and server are run as separate processes, then have different process IDs. 4) if you comment that line, `connect()` should fail, since the `memset()` would have set `sin_addr` to `0.0.0.0` which is not a valid IP to `connect()` to.